# Using fetch and randomuser.me, how do I return multiple results?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to use randomuser.me and I have the fetch request set up properly. I'm returning a single user. However, I want to return 5 comma separated users.

According to [randomuser.me's documentation](https://randomuser.me/documentation#:%7E:text=Random%20User%20Generator%20allows%20you%20to%20fetch%20up%20to), I only need to append the fetch URI with `?results=5` (or any number I choose) and the multiple users are returned.

I've done this in the snippet below, but I'm still only returning a single user.

**How do I return a comma separated result of 5 users?**

```js
window.onload = () => {
  randomUserGenerator();
};

const randomUserGenerator = () => {
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      showRandomUserData(data);
    });
};

showRandomUserData = (randomUser) => {
  document.getElementById("name").innerText = 
    `${randomUser.results[0].name.first} ${randomUser.results[0].name.last}`;
};
```

```html
<h3><u>Users:</u> <span id="name"></span></h3>
```

Comment: `results[0]` ... you're only USING the first user

Comment: Ok. I consoled the data and I can see all 5 there. How do I output them to my HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `results[0]` ... you're only USING the first user

Something like this may help you along

```js
window.onload = () => {
  randomUserGenerator();
};

const randomUserGenerator = () => {
  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      showRandomUserData(data);
    });
};

showRandomUserData = (randomUser) => {
  // combine all users
  const users = randomUser.results.map(({name: { first, last}}) => `${first} ${last}`).join(', ');
  // show them
  document.getElementById("name").innerText = users;
};
```

```html
<h3><u>Users:</u> <span id="name"></span></h3>
```